# Trying to Use LoadMoreElement in Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios

I am using Monotouch to write an Ipad app. The app uses tables to browse down through a directory tree and then select a file. I have used Monotouch.Dialog to browse the directories and I set up the directory tables as the app starts.However there are too many files to set up in a table as the app starts and so I want to set up the 'file table' as the file is selected from the lowest level directory table. I am trying to use LoadMoreElement to do this but I cannot make it work or find any examples online. I have coded the 'Elements API Walkthrough' in the Xamarin tutorial at:- http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MonoTouch.Dialog
I then add a new section to the code:-

```
_addButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {

   ++n;

   var task = new Task{Name = "task " + n, DueDate = DateTime.Now};

   var taskElement = new RootElement (task.Name){
          new Section () {
                  new EntryElement (task.Name,
                         "Enter task description", task.Description)
          },
          new Section () {
                  new DateElement ("Due Date", task.DueDate)
          },
          new Section() 
                {
                     new LoadMoreElement("Passive","Active", 
                                        delegate {MyAction();})
                }

            };
   _rootElement [0].Add (taskElement);
```

Where MyAction is:-

public void MyAction()

{

```
        Console.WriteLine ("we have been actioned");
```

}

The problem is that MyAction is triggered and Console.Writeline writes the message but the table stays in the active state and never returns to passive. the documentation says:-
Once your code in the NSAction is finished, the UIActivity indicator stops animating and the normal caption is displayed again.
What am I missing?

Ian

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "Animating" property in the element to false.

Like this:

LoadMoreElement loadMore = null;

```
 loadMore = new LoadMoreElement (
     "Passive", "Active", 
     delegate {loadMore.Animating = false;});
```

Where did you see any documentation that says that the animation stops when the delegate stops running?   If that is documented anywhere, that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. The documentation I used is the main Dialog tutorial at:-http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MonoTouch.Dialog. There is a single paragraph on  LoadMoreElement which says:-  Once your code in the NSAction is finished, the UIActivity indicator stops animating and the normal caption is displayed again. In the API the LoadMoreElement is not yet documented. Is there anywhere else I should look?